# Notepad Tutorial Android - menu problems

Tags: android, menu, notepad

I am working on the Notepad Tutorial on the Android dev site, part 1. 
I have done all the code as in the tutorial, also tried with the code form the downloaded solution. 
When i launch the app I don't see a button "Add note", and therefore I cannot continue with the tutorial. 
It seems like the methods aren't firing?

All i see is title and the note that says "there are no notes here yet".

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: If I remember correctly, that button should only be visible after you hit the "Menu" key.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I had not tried that... worked like a charm. Feel a bit stupid after rummaging the net like a crazy person looking for a solution. Thanks a a lot!!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :-) We all have our moments, especially on a new and unfamiliar platform :-)